# context state does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i am new to context api, I tried updating the context state by sending a dispatch to the reducer, but when i log the state, i get the default state. however when i inspected inside the react dev tools, i found the the state does have a changed state, but it's just not logging it out in the console, am i doing something wrong?

```
const State = ({ children }) => {
const initState = {
    trending: [],
    search: []
}
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initState)

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state.trending) //returns []
    dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_TRENDING', payload: ['some Data'] })
    console.log(state.trending); // returns [] instead of ['some Data']
    },
 [])}
```

[image: React developer tools inspect screenshot]

Comment: You need to put **state.trending** in the dependency array in the useEffect

Comment: state update is asynchronous and the state is constant within a particular render of a react component; component can only see the updated state _after_ it re-renders. To log the updated state, you can use another `useEffect` hook that executes _after_ state is updated: `useEffect(() => console.log(state), [state]);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to put **state.trending** in the dependency array in the useEffect. So your could would look like:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(state.trending) //returns []
        console.log(state.trending); // returns [] instead of ['some Data']
      },
    [state.trending]) // this is new
    }
```

Also moving the dispatch to a seperate useEffect to avoid infinite rendering.

```
useEffect(() => {
     dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_TRENDING', payload: ['some Data'] })
    },
 [])}
```

Comment: Noted. Removed the dispatch from the useEffect

Comment: if you removed the dispatch, then how would you even expect the state to change?

Comment: Dispatch would be put in the seperate useEffect, updated the answer